# How to use postfix to carbon copy HP ePrint

Tags: postfix, smtp, gentoo

I'd like to print using ePrint using a local e-mail (or alias) like printer@example.com instead of myprinter@hpeprint.com. For what I've already played with the ePrint service from HP, the service won't print anything which have not the myprint@hpeprint as a "to" or "cc" field, meaning that my first attempt of simply creating an alias in the form:

```
printer@example.com myprint@hpeprint.com
```

simply didn't work...

*Googling* and *Stackoverflowing* around lead me to try the recipient_bcc_maps directive, which I did by using:

*file: /etc/postfix/recipient*_bcc_*maps*

```
# recipient_bcc map
printer@example.com myprint@hpeprint.com
```

and:

*file: /etc/postfix/main.cf*

```
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
```

but the following error happens when I try to send any e-mail:

**SMTP Error: [451] 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error**

**EDIT**

The error above was corrected by using postmap to change the file into a hash.

In abstract, I actually need a way that any mail delivered to **print@example.com** generate a copy to **myprint@hpeprint.com** or the "to" field be replaced to **myprint@hpeprint.com**. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're on the right track using the bcc_maps. When you were going through the recipient_bcc_maps and after you added

```
print@example.com myprinter@hpeprint.com
```

Did you use postmap to hash the file? If not, do:

```
/usr/local/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
```

Once that is completed, you need to restart Postfix to apply the change:

```
service postfix stop
service postfix start
```

-Brendan

Comment: the postmap did the trick about changing my file into a hash map and solved the error 451 issue. But no luck printing, guess it's not feasible at all?

Comment: What is /var/log/mail.log showing when you send a test email?

Comment: Oct 26 15:18:52 mail postfix/smtpd[29962]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Oct 26 15:18:53 mail postfix/smtp[29972]: 2F8FF845BD22: to=<myprinter@hpeprint.com>, orig_to=<printer@example.com>, relay=email.hpeprint.com[15.201.224.75]:25, delay=5.1, delays=0.18/0.01/2.2/2.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C2D06D940A9)
Oct 26 15:18:53 mail postfix/smtp[29972]: 2F8FF845BD22: to=<myprinter@hpeprint.com>, relay=email.hpeprint.com[15.201.224.75]:25, delay=5.1, delays=0.18/0.01/2.2/2.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C2D06D940A9)

Comment: and then an e-mail from hp is sent back to me saying there was an error in printing and that The field ‘To’ or ‘Cc’ from the sent email had no printer mail address (Or something like this since it's in portuguese).

Answer (score 1):

I think BCC will not appear in received message.
You can try using canonical maps.
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#canonical_maps